# Photoshop - How to navigate the canvas using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, photoshop-script

How does one **get and set** the following values using Javascript in Adobe Photoshop CS6+:

- Canvas Rotation
- <s>Canvas Zoom</s> (https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1016213)
- Horizontal Window Offset (Panning)
- Vertical Window Offset (Panning)

I see that there is an `app.activeDocument.rotateCanvas()` function, but beyond that...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by offset.

As for rotation. It's quite simple. The amount of rotation desired is measured in degrees & is placed between the brackets. So if you wanted to rotate counter clockwise that would be -90.

e.g.

```
    app.activeDocument.rotateCanvas(-90.0);
```

Comment: By offset I mean the scrollbar positions. I also need to *get* / read the current rotation value.